# How to enable access to a web service hosted on GCP VM instance

Tags: web-services, asp.net-core, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I built a web app, that runs and listens on port 5000 using .netcore (default app in VS).
I created a VM instance on GCP, and allowed http and https traffic in the configuration.
I ran the app, and used the exteral ip(which I succeeded to ping) to access it from the browser:
http://:5000

But I got no response, this should have opened the site.
I added a firewall rule to allow traffic but still didn't help:
[image]
I'm sure many people encountered this, any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same opinion as @Iñigo, it could be the firewall.

You can create the rule with the following command:

```
gcloud compute --project=my-project firewall-rules create rule-for-netcore --direction=INGRESS --priority=1000 --network=default --action=ALLOW --rules=tcp:5000 --source-ranges=0.0.0.0/0
```

The output should be something like:

```
Creating firewall...⠹Created [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project...l/firewalls/rule-for-netcore].
Creating firewall...done.
NAME              NETWORK  DIRECTION  PRIORITY  ALLOW     DENY  DISABLED
rule-for-netcore  default  INGRESS    1000      tcp:5000        False
```

---

#### Edit 1

Also you need to open the port in  your windows firewall:

1. From the **Start** menu, click **Control Panel**, click **System and Security**, and then click **Windows Firewall**. Control Panel is not configured for 'Category' view, you only need to select **Windows Firewall**.
2. Click **Advanced Settings**.
3. Click **Inbound Rules**.
4. Click **New Rule** in the **Actions** window.

[image]

5. Click **Rule Type** of **Port**.
6. Click Next.
7. On the **Protocol and Ports** page click TCP.
8. Select **Specific Local Ports** and type a value something like 5000-5010 (this is only an example you need to add the ports needed)
9. Click Next.
10. On the Action page click **Allow the connection**.
11. Click Next.
12. On the **Profile** page click the appropriate options for your environment.
13. Click Next.
14. On the Name page enter a name of like “Open port for test”
15. Click Finish.
16. **Restart** the Instance.

At the end you would see the rule like this:
[image]

You can consult the following [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/configure-a-firewall-for-report-server-access?view=sql-server-ver15) for more information.

Comment: Hi, I did what you Inigo said using the firewall GUI, I added the same rule.. still couldn't connect.

Comment: Hi, I have added more information to my original answer. Also, you can check if your web server is working properly, I think the following link might help you with your issue. [Troubleshooting Windows Server components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/troubleshoot/windows-server-troubleshooting).

Answer (score 1):

The firewall is dropping your traffic.
You should open port 5000, not http(port 80) or https(port 443).

Comment: Hi,
What you suggest is the most logical, I did it using the GCP GUI, but I'm still not able to connect...